# Crystal Report run time

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have application in C# (.net 2), and I use Crystal Report 11.

When I will distribute the application throughout installer, How can I install Crystal Report run time files?

Is there an easy way other than install the whole Crystal Report Runtime (43 MB)

Comment: Are you using the free version of Crystal Reports that is included with Visual Studio, or are you using a full version of Crystal Reports? I'm assuming this is a Winforms/WPF application, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download the [merge modules from SAP](http://service.sap.com/sap/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm) (Who now own Crystal, of course)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with CR10. It's about 29 Mb of files:

The first file contains some data about CR common file folder. Change/update it if requested:

```
crdeploy.reg
------------
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Crystal Decisions\10.0\Crystal Reports]
"CommonFiles"="c:\\program files\\common files\\crystal decisions\\2.5\\bin"
```

The following files must be put under the CR "common files" folder (as defined in the crDeploy.reg/registery file):

```
C:\pfd\DLL\CRYSTAL_10\TO_COMMONFILES
------------------------------------    
crdb_ado.dll        'if you use an ado connection. There is one specific dll for each type of connexion'
crheapalloc.dll
crtowords_en.dll    'this one is computer/language specific. Transforms numbers '
                    'in words. If your computer is turned into french, you ll'
                    'have to get the corresponding dll to have the function work properly'
crxf_html.dll
crxf_pdf.dll
crxf_rtf.dll
crxf_wordw.dll
crxf_xls.dll
exlate32.dll
GDIPLUS.DLL
Implode.dll
querybuilder.dll
sscdlg.dll
sscsdk80.dll
u252000.dll            'you might not need all of these ....'
u25dts.dll
u25samp1.dll
u2dapp.dll
u2ddisk.dll
u2dmapi.dll
u2dpost.dll
u2fcr.dll
u2frdef.dll
u2frec.dll
u2fsepv.dll
u2ftext.dll
u2fxml.dll
u2l2000.dll
u2lcom.dll
u2ldts.dll
u2lexch.dll
u2lfinra.dll
ufmanager.dll
```

The following files must be in the same folder and must be registered through regsvr32

```
C:\pfd\DLL\CRYSTAL_10\TO_COMMONFILES\TO_REGISTER
----------------------------------------------
CRAnalyzer.dll
craxdrt.dll          'is the free dll for manipulating report objects.'
                     'You can use the licensed 'craxddrt.dll' that allows'
                     'you to modify reports at runtime.'
crqe.dll
crtslv.dll
crviewer.dll         'is the dll for the viewer you can display on your GUI'
ExportModeller.dll
keycode.dll
pageObjectModel.dll
ReportRenderer.dll
webReporting.dll
```

The following files shall be added to the system folder (can be already available from other sources ...)

```
C:\pfd\DLL\CRYSTAL_10\TO_SYSTEM
-------------------------------
cxlibw-1-6.dll
dbghelp.dll
msvcrt.dll
riched20.dll
usp10.dll
```

Comment: Possibly worth pointing out that this would violate most of the EULAs for the software invloved...

Comment: No. As long as you do not distribute the 'craxddrt.dll' library, all other are free of use.